# Pass in name of function in req.params node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a file called helpers.js which contains the following

```
var helpers = {
  add: function(a,b){
    return a+b;
  },
  sub: function(a,b){
    return a-b;
  },
  mult: function(a,b){
    return a*b;
  },
  div: function(a,b){
    return a/b;
  },
  math: function(a,b,callback){
    return callback(a,b);
  }
};

module.exports = helpers;
```

In my app.js I am including

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
ejs = require("ejs"),
helpers = require("./helpers");
```

and am trying to have a user pass in the name of a function as a parameter with this code here:

```
app.get('/number/:num1/:num2/:operation', function(req,res){

  var a = parseInt(req.params.num1);
  var b = parseInt(req.params.num2);
  var operation = req.params.operation;
  var result = helpers.operation(a,b);


  res.render('math', {result: result});
});
```

Since the variable operation is a string, I am getting the error Object # has no method 'operation'. Is there any way to convert this parameter into a function? Or is there a better way to try to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the function with `helpers[operation]`, just make sure that it's a valid function name first, otherwise you will get a `TypeError` exception.

```
var result = helpers[operation](a, b);
```